# Can I create custom keybord in Malayalam Language(Language in India)

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I need to create a customized keyboard,which should display letters in Malayalam(Language using in India).I know custom keyboard which contain English and letters are quite essay.But trying to add other languages like Malayalam it not displaying any data.I refer some example programs

https://github.com/alanszlosek/android-keyboard

https://github.com/alanszlosek/android-keyboard

http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html -this tutorial help me a lot.But when I inserting Malayalam Letters it showing squares only,not displaying proper letter.

please help me....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to solve the above given problem.

1.Download the Malayalam font and store in the assets manager.
  then call like

```
      Typeface typeNormal = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "AnjaliOldLipi.ttf");
```

where  'AnjaliOldLipi.ttf' is one Malayalam font supported by android.

2.If we need to set the edit text box, which support Malayalam font. then

```
      EditText mEt ;
       mEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xEt);
        mEt.setTypeface(typeNormal);
```

3.If need to set any buttons in Malayalam font

```
Button mB;
mB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x1);
    mB.setTypeface(typeNormal);
    mB.setText("അ");
    mB.setTag("അ");
```

4.Go through this link- http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html  that will help you a lot to create custom keyboard in android